# Laravel application stuck using Octane after x amount of requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-octane

I'm currently upgrading an application to use Octane. At a glance I thought this was working great until I used K6 to do some load testing.

It might be worth mentioning at this point that I'm using Docker.

When running a 60s test with 20 vus I can see all the requests hitting (via CLI logs) and then at about 99% the logs stop and then test finishes with request timeout errors (99% success).

If I try to visit the application locally the requests are in a constant pending state (never terminates).

If I enter the container and try to interact with the application it simply does nothing (like the request, constantly hanging). I cant even exit the container at this point. If I try to kill the container I can't, I have to restart Docker.

If I cut the vus down to 10, the test finishes successfully. If I run the test again at about half way through it again dies.

It's as if once the application hits x amount of requests, it dies.

Also note that I have run these tests many times before installing Octane and they ran fine.

Has anyone else had any experience with Octane who has experienced the above?

Regards

Comment: Encountering the same issue, different config: wsl1, latest version of Laravel, octane and nova. Have you found anything?

Comment: Not yet no and we have it running in UAT fine so guessing its a Docker "thing".

Comment: Turned out to be Swoole on WSL1 not playing nicely with chunked transfer. https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3858 https://github.com/swoole/swoole-src/issues/2386